# Function to return sum of *Fraction objects in an array not working

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, function, pointers

For the code below...
1) Is `*sumFrac`, located within the function, released when I call `[result release]` in the main program? 
2) Why am I receiver a compiler error when I attempt to release the Fraction array object with `[fractionArray release]` ?
3) Finally, the function does not actually return a sum, but `0/0`.  Why might this be?

I'm sorry if this is obvious, it is new to me...  Thank you

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Fraction.h>

Fraction * arraySum (Fraction *fracArray[], int arrayLength)
{
    Fraction *sumFrac = [[Fraction alloc] init];
    Fraction **fractsPtr;

    for ( fractsPtr = fracArray; fractsPtr < arrayLength; ++fractsPtr )
        sumFrac = [*fractsPtr add: *(fractsPtr + 1)];

    return sumFrac;
}

//Test function
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Fraction *result;

    Fraction *a = [[Fraction alloc] initWith: 3 over: 5];
    Fraction *b = [[Fraction alloc] initWith: 2 over: 7];
    Fraction *c = [[Fraction alloc] initWith: 6 over: 3];

    Fraction *fractionArray[] = { a, b, c };

    result = arraySum ( fractionArray, 2 );

    [result print];

    [result release];
    [a release];
    [b release];
    [c release];
    [fractionArray release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the future, don't just say "a compiler error", show the error message. They're usually chock full of useful information (especially when the compiler is clang).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is *sumFrac, located within the function, released when I call [result release] in the main program?

This is sort of a trick question.

`sumFrac` itself is just a pointer to the object. When you copy a pointer around—whether through direct assignment with `=`, passing as a parameter, returning from a function, etc.—that's just copying a pointer. So, `result` is a pointer to the same object as `sumFrac`. So, when you send it a `release`, it's just like sending a release to `sumFrac`.

(If you were using ARC, this actually gets more complicated, because just copying a pointer sometimes automatically does refcount stuff. But it also becomes the compiler's problem rather than yours, as long as you use proper names or attributes.)

However, you repeatedly assign a new value to `sumFrac`. Each time you do this, it stops pointing at the old value. Nothing `release`s the old value, or `retain`s the new one. So, the value you return as `sumFrac` *does* get released—but, unless `arrayLength` was 0, that's not the same value you allocated in the first line. I'm not even sure why you're allocating a `Fraction` object when you're just going to ignore it in favor of a different one, but if you want to make this work, you can:

```
for ( fractsPtr = fracArray; fractsPtr < arrayLength; ++fractsPtr )
    [sumFrac release];
    sumFrac = [[*fractsPtr add: *(fractsPtr + 1)] retain];
```

Now, each time you reassign `sumFrac`, you first release the old object and retain the new one, so each `Fraction` ends up with the same number of refs it started with (including the useless new one having 0 refs), except that the one you return has one extra ref, which you later `release` in the main function. (I'm assuming here that `-[add:]` returns a new, autoreleased `Fraction`. If it instead modifies the object in place, or returns a new +1 `Fraction`, or something else, that's a different story.)

If you're having a hard time keeping refcounts straight, you might want to consider following the standard naming conventions and/or using autorelease pools and/or ARC. (It's worth noting that you already *have* an autorelease pool.) Or, alternatively, use Leaks and the other tools that come with Xcode to watch things, or add in code that dumps out the refcounts so you can see them later.

> 2) Why am I receiver a compiler error when I attempt to release the Fraction array object with [fractionArray release] ?

Because `fractionArray` is a `Fraction*[]`—that is, a C-style array of `Fraction` objects, not a `Fraction` object. You can't send a message to a C-style array, only to an object.

In fact, the error or warning (depending on your compiler settings) that you get here already explains this:

```
frac.m:61:6: warning: receiver type 'Fraction **' is not 'id' or interface pointer,
      consider casting it to 'id'
    [fractionArray release];
```

In order to understand that, you have to know that an `id` is a type that means "pointer to any ObjC object" and that a pointer to a pointer to an object is not the same thing as a pointer to an object, so that may not have been enough for you. But if you'd posted the error message instead of just saying "I got a compiler error", you would have gotten an immediate answer.

If you want to do things this way, you have to send `release` to each `Fraction` object in the array. Which you're already doing with the `[a release]`, etc. You don't have to do anything at all to the array, because it's allocated on the stack (and if you had allocated it with, e.g., `malloc`, you'd want to `free` it, not `release` it.) So, you're done.

But a better way to do things is to create an ObjC array, which *is* an object:

```
NSArray *fractionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: a, b, c, nil];
// ...
[fractionArray release];
```

(Except in that case, you don't actually want to `release` it anyway, because `arrayWithObjects:` returns an autoreleased array, and you've got an autorelease pool, so don't get in the way of the pool.)

> 3) Finally, the function does not actually return a sum, but 0/0. Why might this be?

Let's look at your loop:

```
for ( fractsPtr = fracArray; fractsPtr < arrayLength; ++fractsPtr )
```

If you're going to do things C-style, you start running into C errors instead of ObjC errors… You're comparing `fractsPtr < arrayLength`. This will convert the two into comparable types, then compare them. `fractsPtr` is a pointer into an array on your stack, so it's obviously not less than 2. You need to do one of the following:

```
for ( fractsPtr = fracArray; fractsPtr < fracArray+arrayLength; ++fractsPtr )
```

… or

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
    fractsPtr = fracArray[i];
```

I'd be very surprised if this compiled without warnings. Trying it myself, I get this:

```
frac.m:34:44: warning: ordered comparison between pointer and integer
      ('Fraction **' and 'int')
    for ( fractsPtr = fracArray; fractsPtr < arrayLength; ++fractsPtr )
```

Warnings are there for a reason. I would have spotted the answer immediately if I'd seen this, instead of wasting time trying to guess what `add:` might be doing, etc. Even if the warning doesn't explain the problem to *you*, at least mention it in your question.

If you fix this, what will happen? Well, each time through the loop, it assigns `sumFracs` to `[*fractsPtr add: *(fractsPtr+1)];` Only the last assignment matters. So, it still won't be summing all of the fractions, just the last two—in other words, it's going to be the same as `[fracArray[arrayLength-1] add:fracArray[arrayLength]]`.

Also, using a parameter named `arrayLength` when it actually means 1 less than the array length is an invitation to disaster. You knew to call `arraySum(fractionArray, 2)` because you'd just written the code, but when you come back to it in a few weeks, you're going to write `arraySum(fractionArray, 3)` (or `arraySum(fractionArray, sizeof(fractionArray)/sizeof(*fractionArray))`), and it will look so obviously right that you'll have no idea why you're reading garbage values or segfaulting.

Comment: Great help!  Just to clarify: although I call `release` on `result`, it will release `sumFrac` (because I assigned it to result)?  Also - might you have insight on why the function does not compute a sum?  Thanks again

Comment: OK, answer updated. But now that I look more carefully… yes, it will release `sumFrac`, but that probably doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: Very thorough answer.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oops, hold on… yet another problem I just noticed. Editing again.

Answer (score 2):

That code is highly odd.

You don't have an array object at all;  you have some rather oddly managed language arrays.

I would suggest refactoring the code to use `NSMutableArray` to contain your fractions as you'll pretty much never see code like what you've written in real ObjC apps.

Comment: Yes, it is a roundabout way of doing it.  I only coded it like that because I was working on some ObjC exercises covering those topics, but it is good to know I won't often need to deal with code like this IRL